# rails Passing array of records (in JSON)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I have generated an array of records in JSON format in Javascript and I want to create multiple records in controller. I pass these data:

```
[
{"trip_id":0,"arrival_time":0,"departure_time":0,"stop_id":0,"stop_sequence":0},{"trip_id":1,"arrival_time":1,"departure_time":1,"stop_id":1,"stop_sequence":1},
{"trip_id":2,"arrival_time":2,"departure_time":2,"stop_id":2,"stop_sequence":2},{"trip_id":3,"arrival_time":3,"departure_time":3,"stop_id":3,"stop_sequence":3},
{"trip_id":4,"arrival_time":4,"departure_time":4,"stop_id":4,"stop_sequence":4},{"trip_id":5,"arrival_time":5,"departure_time":5,"stop_id":5,"stop_sequence":5},
{"trip_id":6,"arrival_time":6,"departure_time":6,"stop_id":6,"stop_sequence":6},{"trip_id":7,"arrival_time":7,"departure_time":7,"stop_id":7,"stop_sequence":7},
{"trip_id":8,"arrival_time":8,"departure_time":8,"stop_id":8,"stop_sequence":8},{"trip_id":9,"arrival_time":9,"departure_time":9,"stop_id":9,"stop_sequence":9}
]
```

I'm trying to do it more or less this way:

```
def create
params.each do |stop_time|
  StopTime.create stop_time
end
...
```

, but I don't know how to get each record (as :id ? or something else?).

Thanks,

Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually a key in your params object that is associated with this data. Can you give more information about what is in the params hash? Otherwise, I'd say that's all you're missing.

```
params[:some_key_with_that_array_of_stop_times].each do |stop_time|
  StopTime.create stop_time
end
```

Comment: I've mad it this way. Thanks for tip @liamneesonsarmsauce :)
  
     `stop_times = params['_json']  
     stop_times.each do |stop_time|
         StopTime.create(stop_time)
     end`